# Trouble Installing / Running

Tags: python, python-3.x, openmdao

I installed openmdao via the documentation here (windows 10 plus anaconda): http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/getting_started/getting_started.html

If I actually use the [all] flag it seems that pip tries to download every version of the packages so I just went with `pip install openmdao`

When I try to run the sample from the above link I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Problem' object has no attribute 'model'
```

I tried re-running in spyder with the same error then tried the first few lines just in the terminal to verify no model attribute existed.

I tried to skip further down into the code with terminal and got some more errors:

```
prob.driver=om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-8ea598efdab2>", line 1, in <module>
    prob.driver=om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()

AttributeError: module 'openmdao.api' has no attribute 'ScipyOptimizeDriver'
```

I assumed that maybe there is a disconnect with the different versions floating around with openmdao so I then installed the latest non-dev version and tried to run a few included files in that master folder. All the examples I ran had the same error though:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Vicconius/Anaconda3/OpenMDAO1-master/examples/beam_tutorial.py', wdir='C:/Users/Vicconius/Anaconda3/OpenMDAO1-master/examples')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-7e855a208cb8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Vicconius/Anaconda3/OpenMDAO1-master/examples/beam_tutorial.py', wdir='C:/Users/Vicconius/Anaconda3/OpenMDAO1-master/examples')

  File "C:\Users\Vicconius\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Vicconius\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Vicconius/Anaconda3/OpenMDAO1-master/examples/beam_tutorial.py", line 218, in <module>
    top.setup()

  File "C:\Users\Vicconius\Anaconda3\OpenMDAO1-master\openmdao\core\problem.py", line 456, in setup
    connections = self._setup_connections(params_dict, unknowns_dict)

  File "C:\Users\Vicconius\Anaconda3\OpenMDAO1-master\openmdao\core\problem.py", line 234, in _setup_connections
    for node in input_graph.nodes_iter():

AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'nodes_iter'
```

Any ideas? THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine two scenarios:

1. you happened to create an `openmdao` folder in your current local directory. You're opening the interpreter or otherwise running python scripts in that same directory. So when you try `import openmdao` it picks the local folder first --- instead of the installed package. If thats the case, either `cd` to a different directory or rename/remove that folder.
2. Something has gone wrong with your install. You somehow have multiple conflicting versions sitting around.
   To test, first uninstall with pip:
   `pip uninstall OpenMDAO`.
   Then open an interpreter and try
   `import openmdao`
   If that somehow works, after you just uninstalled it, that confirms that you somehow have multiple installs.
   you need to manually clean up your environment.
   inside the interpreter, `openmdao.__file__` should tell you where this wonky second install is hiding. You can go delete it manually, and then repeat this import test till you get an `ImportError`. At that point you know you have found all the rouge installs and you can safely retry a new pip install.

Comment: Thanks for the info I learned a few things! I ended up just switching to WSL because I'm a lot more comfortable in a Linux environment regarding python and the process went a lot more smoothly.